# Keyboard not showing when displaying over other apps application

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing the feature "displaying over other apps" in android, I found [this](https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/amp/?amp_gsa=1&amp_js_v=a9&usqp=mq331AQIUAKwASCAAgM%3D#amp_tf=De%20%251%24s&aoh=17057206470825&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fhow-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android%2F) source from geeksforgeeks. The application works well, however the keyboard is not being showing.

[image]

This is my code:
manifest.xml ;

```
    <!-- add required permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"

      ...

        <!-- register the service -->

        <service
            android:name=".ForegroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse">
            <property android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE" android:value="foo"/>  <!-- optional -->

        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Window.java

```
package com.example.drawoverotherapps;

import static android.content.Context.WINDOW_SERVICE;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Window {


    // declaring required variables

    private Context context;

    private View mView;

    private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    private float dX, dY;

    public Window(Context context){

        this.context=context;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // set the layout parameters of the window

            mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(

                    // Shrink the window to wrap the content rather

                    // than filling the screen

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

                    // Display it on top of other application windows

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,

                    // Don't let it grab the input focus

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,

                    // Make the underlying application window visible

                    // through any transparent parts

                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);



        }

        // getting a LayoutInflater

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // inflating the view with the custom layout we created

        mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);


        // the view from the window
        EditText editText = mView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
        editText.requestFocus();

        // set onClickListener on the remove button, which removes
        mView.findViewById(R.id.window_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

                close();

            }

        });

        // Define the position of the

        // window within the screen

        mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        mParams.y=500;

        mParams.flags = mParams.flags | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;


        mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    }



    public void open() {

        try {

            // check if the view is already

            // inflated or present in the window

            if(mView.getWindowToken()==null) {

                if(mView.getParent()==null) {

                    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams);

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("Error1",e.toString());

        }
    }


    public void close() {



        try {

            // remove the view from the window

            ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);

            // invalidate the view

            mView.invalidate();

            // remove all views

            ((ViewGroup)mView.getParent()).removeAllViews();



            // the above steps are necessary when you are adding and removing

            // the view simultaneously, it might give some exceptions

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("Error2",e.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

so so, all the code can be found on [this-repo](https://github.com/alcarazolabs/display-over-other-apps-java). However the core of code is in "Window.java" that we can see above.

Is possible show the keyboard by using this feature? what is wrong on window.java or I should need add another flags? The editText has the requestFocus() added, however the keyboard hasn't appears.

Any idea guys to fix this problem I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance.